# Illegal offset type on save a one to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a `Package` model like this :

```
class Package extends Model
    {

        protected $primaryKey = 'package_id';
        protected $fillable   = ['title', 'slug', 'desc'];

        public function options ()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Option', 'package_id', 'package_id');
        }
    }
```

And a `Option` model like this :

```
class Option extends Model
    {
        public    $timestamps = false;
        protected $primaryKey = ['option_id'];
        protected $fillable   = ['package_id','text'];

        public function package ()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Package', 'package_id', 'package_id');
        }
    }
```

As you can see there is a **One to Many** relationship between them.

Now I want save some new Options for a new created Package. for that I wrote this controller method :

```
public function store (StorePackageRequest $request)
        {

            $data    = $request->except('options');

            $package = Package::create($data);

            $options = $request->get('options');

            $opts = [];
            foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
                $opts[] = new Option(['text' => $option]);
            }

            $package->options()->saveMany($opts);

            $result = ['success' => true, 'generated_id' => $package->package_id];

            return $result;
        }
```

`options` parameter that comes from `$request->get('options')` are some input element like this :

```
<input type="text" name="options[]" class="form-control">
```

But On first rotation of foreach loop I got this error :

```
ErrorException in HasAttributes.php line 818:
Illegal offset type
```

What is problem ?

**Update :**

Full Error :

```
[2017-08-07 16:49:50] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Illegal offset type' in D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php:818
Stack trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(818): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Illegal offset ...', 'D:\\wamp\\www\\bra...', 818, Array)
#1 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(803): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getCasts()
#2 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(832): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->hasCast('text', Array)
#3 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(565): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->isDateCastable('text')
#4 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(525): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->isDateAttribute('text')
#5 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(223): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setAttribute('text', 'a')
#6 D:\wamp\www\brands\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(145): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fill(Array)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine the reason you're having this issue is because you have the `$primarykey` set to be an array in your `Option` model.

Try changing it to:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'option_id';
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [API](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Request.html), `get()` method does not exist for `Request`.

Instead of `$request->get('options')`, try `$request->input('options')`.

Comment: I tried your code but does not solve and get same error

Comment: Mmh ok! And in your `Option` model, if you change your `$primaryKey` from array to string?